# Using the reference data type in Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I want to define a rule that allows a user only to update his own items and an admin to update all.

As `uid_of_logged_in_administrator` I should be able to update both `items/item__1` and `items/item__2` - this works.

As `uid_of_logged_in_user` I should be allowed to update `items/item__1` but not `items/item__2` - this does not.

Obviously the problem is I do not know what the data type [**Cloud Firestore references**] represents in rules.

I've read through the documentation on rules and been trying different things.

```
if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner                           | false
if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner.id                        | false
if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner.__id__                    | false
if resource.data.owner is string                                     | false
if resource.data.owner is path                                       | true
if resource.data.owner == path('users/uid_of_logged_in_user')        | false 
if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner[6]                        | false
```

So it seems that the resource.data.owner is a path.

**But how do I obtain the id for this reference?**

One of my reasons for creating this reference is then the owner property can either be a box or an user. eg. `{owner: '/users/uid_of_logged_in_user'}`, `{owner: '/boxes/box__1'}`

I could of course just add a property with the users uid as a string to the item instead of as a reference. But then i would need to have two diffrent properties for box or user as owner.

### My rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isAdmin() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin";
    }
    function isAuth() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read:   if isAuth();
      allow write:  if isAdmin();
    }

    match /items/{umbId} {
      allow read:   if isAuth();
      // THIS IS THE ISSUE. IT DOESENT WORK.
      allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner 
      allow write:  if isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

### The structure of my database is as follows

```
users 
  # documentid(uid_of_logged_in_user)
    - name: 'My name'                                           // string
    - address: 'My address'                                     // string
  # documentid(uid_of_logged_in_administrator)
    - name: 'Another one'                                       // string
    - address: 'His address'                                    // string
    - role: 'admin'

items
  # documentid(item__1)
    - owner: 'users/uid_of_logged_in_user'                      // reference
    - name: 'The first item'                                    // string
  # documentid(item__2)
    - owner: 'users/uid_of_logged_in_administrator'             // reference
    - name: 'The first item'                                    // string

boxes
  # documentid(box__1)
    - name: 'First Box'                                         // string
  documentid(box__2)
    - name: 'Second box'                                        // string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if resource.data.owner == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid_of_logged_in_user)` should work.

Comment: Thanks a million @mono. The only part missing was the leading forward slash before databases. :) But now it works!

Comment: Oh, I mistook. I corrected it by adding the slash :)

Comment: I got confused on a project with this, was trying to use path() constructor like get or exists after skimming docs. Its obvious if I took my time, where the slash form is the "'raw' form", and the path constructor takes a string which the raw form was not, with path(path) errors