# Firestore security rule should not allow deletion, but it allows

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase security rules do not seem to be working.

I want it to be forbidden to delete other's person objects.
I configured rule for delete:

```
if resource == null || request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner
```

I have test that verifies the request fails if user tries to delete other's object. However, the request succeeds.

These are my all security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collection}/{document} {
      allow create: 
        if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner

        && (collection != "Person" 
            || request.resource.data.owner == request.resource.data.id)
      allow update: 
        if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner
        && request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner

        && (collection != "Person" 
            || request.resource.data.owner == request.resource.data.id)
      allow get, delete: 
        if resource == null
        || request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner
      allow list:
        if collection == "XfCard"
    }
  }
}
```

What can be missing?

Comment: Rules don't have much meaning without data and queries paired with it.  Please edit the question to show the query (with all exact values - no variables), the exact data it's working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging I found out that the request succeeds, but the object is NOT deleted. 
My HTTP request just does not return error message.

Answer (score 0):

The `resource.data.owner` is more a path than a variable that you can use to compare to another. Considering that, it's usually needed that you set this as a specific path and not just perform the direct, usual comparison.

As seen in this other question from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340047/using-the-reference-data-type-in-firestore-rules), it's usually necessary to compare the owner with the path of the owner of document, something, more or less like the below code:

```
if resource.data.owner == /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(uid_owner)
```

This way, you should be able to use it and confirm the identity of the owner, in relation to the document.

In addition to checking the above Community post and giving a try using the above code - **not tested**, but I believe it's a good starting point - , I would recommend you to take a look at the below official documentation, that you can find more information on security rules for group queries.

- [Collection group queries and security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules)

Let me know if the information helped you!